# How to sort/order a list by date in dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following list, that I am trying to re-order/ sort by the DateTime.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart'; 
//don't forget to add under dependencies pubspec.yml "intl: ^0.15.8"


List products = [];

//adding into the new list from raw API list
for(final item in rawProducts){

   var parsedDate = DateTime.parse.(item['expiryDate']);
   tmpArray = {
     'id': item['id'],
     'name': item['name'],
     'price': item['price'],
     'expiry': parsedDate
   }
   products.add(tmpArray);
  }
}


List products = [

 {id: 1242, name: milk, price: $5, expiry: 2019-11-25 00:00:00:000},
 {id: 1242, name: egg, price: $2, expiry: 2019-11-22 00:00:00:000},
 {id: 1243, name: bread, price: $3, expiry: 2019-11-22 00:00:00:000},
 {id: 1244, name: butter, price: $7, expiry: 2019-11-24 00:00:00:000},
 {id: 1247, name: butter, price: $7, expiry: 2019-11-23 00:00:00:000},

]
```

I would like to re-order the list in a way that the farthest expiry date shows up first:

```
 25-11-2019
 24-11-2019
 23-11-2019
 22-11-2019
 22-11-2019
```

What I have tried (updated) -> SOLVED by changing `a.expiry` into `a['expiry']` :

```
  products.sort((a,b) {
    var adate = a['expiry'] //before -> var adate = a.expiry;
     var bdate = b['expiry'] //var bdate = b.expiry;
     return -adate.compareTo(bdate);
  });
```

on the sort function I am receiving this error (SOLVED by above fix):

```
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 
'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>'has no instance getter 'expiry'.
```

Comment: see `DateFormat.parse` method

Comment: thank you, I have already parsed the date before assigning it to the products , please see the update above

Comment: `final format = DateFormat('yyyy-M-d H:m:s:S');
final array = [
  '2019-11-24 00:00:00:000',
  '2019-11-22 00:00:00:000',
  '2019-11-23 00:00:00:000',
  '2019-11-25 00:00:00:000',
  '2019-11-22 00:00:00:000',
];

array.map(format.parse).toList()
  ..sort((a, b) => -a.compareTo(b))
  ..forEach(print);`

Comment: thank you @pskink, seems the error is actually coming from the sort method trying to get `expiry` throws this error : `Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance getter 'expiry'`

Comment: thank you @pskink, yes I did, I'm getting this error `has no instance of  getter 'expiry' please see the last segment of the question above.

Comment: no, my code does not have any `expiry`, first run my code as it is (without any changes), see how it works and finally change your code accordingly - basically the key is in `DateFormat()` constructor and how `sort` method is handled

Comment: @pskink,thank you!! i got it to work, sorry yes i didn't run your code separately my bad was just modifying my own codes. So it was actually on the `a.expiry` , i switched it to `a['expiry']` it re-orders properly now, I have tried switching `adate.compareTo(bdate)` and `-bdate.compareTo(adate)` to confirm and the order is working amazing! thank you so much. can you post it as an answer, so i can mark it please?

Comment: sure, your welcome, feel free to post a self answer

Comment: I have posted my answer, thank you @pskink!! happy coding :)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

In your example above, `expiry` is a `String`, not a DateTime object. You have a few options here, depending on what you want to achieve.

The easiest solution would be to use String's built in [`compareTo`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/String/compareTo.html) method, which allows sorting Strings. Those timestamps are already in a sortable format, so this would work:

```dart
products.sort((a,b) {
    return a.compareTo(b);
 });
```

Or more concise:

```dart
products.sort((a,b) => a.compareTo(b));
```

This is pretty basic. Like pskink mentioned in the comment, building on this you could convert the Strings to actual DateTime objects.

```
DateTime expiryAsDateTime = DateTime.parse(expiry);
```

`DateTime` also has a built in `compareTo` method, so the code snippet above would work with DateTimes as well as Strings.

If you want to reverse the order, just swap `a` and `b`.

Comment: thank you @MichaelM for your answer, I have already parsed the date before assigning it into the products list. BTW what order will this actually return? what if i want the opposite order how can i modify this function you have mentioned above `products.sort((a,b) => a.compareTo(b));`

Comment: compareTo sorts in ascending order. If you want to swap the order you can just  do this: `products.sort((a,b) => b.compareTo(a));` I've linked the documentation in my answer

Comment: nice! thank you @MichaelM, now the error is mainly on the sort function after checking the log, i think the sort function is unable to access the `expiry` in the list. please see the last segment of my updated question for the error

Comment: thank you! I have fixed the error  using your first suggested method!

Answer (score 28):

I fixed it by changing  `changing a.expiry into a['expiry']` and `b.expiry into b['expiry']`

```
products.sort((a,b) {
 var adate = a['expiry'] //before -> var adate = a.expiry;
 var bdate = b['expiry'] //before -> var bdate = b.expiry;
 return adate.compareTo(bdate); //to get the order other way just switch `adate & bdate`
});
```

Answer (score 19):

**convert to DateTime**

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  List products = [
    "2019-11-25 00:00:00.000",
    "2019-11-22 00:00:00.000",
    "2019-11-22 00:00:00.000",
    "2019-11-24 00:00:00.000",
    "2019-11-23 00:00:00.000"
  ];
  List<DateTime> newProducts = [];
  DateFormat format = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    newProducts.add(format.parse(products[i]));
  }
  newProducts.sort((a,b) => a.compareTo(b));

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    print(newProducts[i]);
  }
}
```

**without convert to DateTime**

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  List products = [
    "2019-11-25 00:00:00.000",
    "2019-11-22 00:00:00.000",
    "2019-11-22 00:00:00.000",
    "2019-11-24 00:00:00.000",
    "2019-11-23 00:00:00.000"
  ];

  products.sort((a,b) => a.compareTo(b));

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    print(products[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

If you have something like:

```
{
"id": 100,
"timestamp": "2021-02-02T15:15:11Z",
"name": "Entry1"
}
```

Then do this:

```
List<Values> _myList = [];
_myList.sort((a,b)=> a["timestamp"].compareTo(b["timestamp"]));
```

Or like in my code:

```
task.sort((a,b) => a.createdAt.compareTo(b.createdAt));
```

[Source](https://cloudstack.ninja/bradg/how-to-sort-a-list-in-flutter/)

Answer (score 12):

If we get more specific then try like this one.

its worked perfectly for me

```
transactionList.sort((a, b) {
  int aDate = DateTime.parse(a.dateTime ?? '').microsecondsSinceEpoch;
  int bDate = DateTime.parse(b.dateTime ?? '').microsecondsSinceEpoch;
  return aDate.compareTo(bDate);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to sort the objects by a property name without having to use DateTime assuming the date and time is a string, do this:

```
products.sort((a, b)=> a['expiry'].compareTo(b['expiry']));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to use `DateTime.parse` first before `compareTo`.

Source: https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/169/how-to-sort-list-by-date-in-dart-flutter/

Answer (score 0):

None of these works and if you want to sort by createDate of the item, it means you want to sort by id indeed. So you can use : list.sort((h, c) => c.id.compareTo(h.id));