# How to sort/order a list according to time in 00:00 format?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this list and I would like to sort it on my screen according to the time ["timein"]. does anyone have any idea how can i do this?

```
[{weekday: segunda, description: Química, nametag: Estudos, numbercolortags: [33, 150, 243], timein: 18:30, timeout: 20:00}, {weekday: segunda, description: Física, nametag: Estudos, numbercolortags: [33, 150, 243], timein: 11:00, timeout: 12:00}, {weekday: segunda, description: Biologia, nametag: Estudos, numbercolortags: [33, 150, 243], timein: 22:00, timeout: 23:00}]
```

Comment: hh:mm .........

Comment: [This question may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000166/how-to-sort-order-a-list-by-date-in-dart-flutter)

Comment: `timein: 11:00, timeout: 12:00` is neither legal JSON or legal Dart.  What is a sample of the data precisely?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53547997/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
void main() {
  json.sort((x, y) => '${x['time']}'.seconds.compareTo('${y['time']}'.seconds));
  for (final element in json) {
    print(element);
  }
}

final json = [
  {'id': 1, 'time': '10:00:01'},
  {'id': 3, 'time': '30:00'},
  {'id': 2, 'time': '20:00'},
  {'id': 4, 'time': '40:00'},
  {'id': 0, 'time': '10:00'},
];

extension _Time on String {
  int get seconds {
    var hours = 0;
    var minutes = 0;
    var seconds = 0;
    final parts = split(':');
    switch (parts.length) {
      case 2:
        minutes = _toInt(parts[0], 59);
        seconds = _toInt(parts[1], 59);
        break;
      case 3:
        hours = _toInt(parts[0], 23);
        minutes = _toInt(parts[1], 59);
        seconds = _toInt(parts[2], 59);
        break;
      default:
        _error();
    }

    return hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds;
  }

  void _error() {
    throw FormatException('Invalid time format: $this');
  }

  int _toInt(String part, int max) {
    final result = int.tryParse(part, radix: 10);
    if (result == null) {
      _error();
    }

    if (result < 0 || result > max) {
      _error();
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{id: 0, time: 10:00}
{id: 1, time: 10:00:01}
{id: 2, time: 20:00}
{id: 3, time: 30:00}
{id: 4, time: 40:00}
```

Comment: The best thanks is the accepted answer (accept and upvote).

Comment: Thank you. You ask, other people answer. Then you rate. These are the rules of good form. I also rated your question.