# How to sort a List of items based on dateTime in Flutter | Flutter

Tags: flutter, sorting, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have List of products with product name and date. I want to sort that list of items based on date and time. This is the list of items that i want to sort,

```
List items = [
    {
      "productName":"Icecream",
      "date":"2019-10-17 10:06:12.278"
    },
    {
      "productName":"Juice",
      "date":"2021-09-20 19:08:16.274"
    },
    {
      "productName":"Rice",
      "date":"2020-05-13 08:02:16.177"
    },
    {
      "productName":"Cheese",
      "date":"2021-10-23 20:02:16.254"
    },
    {
      "productName":"Sugar",
      "date":"2019-11-22 00:00:00.000"
    },
  ];
```

This is the Expected Output what i want,

```
List sortedList = [
    {
      "productName":"Icecream",
      "date":"2019-10-17 10:06:12.278"
    },
    {
      "productName":"Sugar",
      "date":"2019-11-22 00:00:00.000"
    },
    {
      "productName":"Rice",
      "date":"2020-05-13 08:02:16.177"
    },
    {
      "productName":"Juice",
      "date":"2021-09-20 19:08:16.274"
    },
    {
      "productName":"Cheese",
      "date":"2021-10-23 20:02:16.254"
    },
  ];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort/order a list by date in dart/flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000166/how-to-sort-order-a-list-by-date-in-dart-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple code using the build-in function `.compareTo` that can help you out:

```dart
void main() async {
  List items = [
    {"productName": "Icecream", "date": "2019-10-17 10:06:12.278"},
    {"productName": "Juice", "date": "2021-09-20 19:08:16.274"},
    {"productName": "Rice", "date": "2020-05-13 08:02:16.177"},
    {"productName": "Cheese", "date": "2021-10-23 20:02:16.254"},
    {"productName": "Sugar", "date": "2019-11-22 00:00:00.000"},
  ];

  // You can change the position of `a` and `b` to get a reversed result
  // as well
  items.sort((a, b) => a['date'].compareTo(b['date']));

  print(items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `compareTo` method in list to compare results based on these results you can sort list using `.sort` method on list